# Resizing UICollectionViewCell and it's contents using AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to add a [custom button](https://github.com/herinkc/HTPressableButton) to a [custom UICollectionViewCell](https://github.com/minhntran/MTCardLayout)

Because I can't add the custom button in Interface Builder (need to alloc it with a specific method), I added an UIView that acts as a placeholder for it which has a clear background (black for demonstration in this question).

This is how it looks like:

[image]

And then in code in the custom class for the UICollectonViewCell I do:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
// Initialization code
self.btnAddOrRemove = [[HTPressableButton alloc] initWithFrame:self.btnContainerView.bounds buttonStyle:HTPressableButtonStyleRounded];
self.btnAddOrRemove.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x, self.btnAddOrRemove.center.y);
//self.btnContainerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];

CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
if (self.shadowWidth != bounds.size.width)
{
    if (self.shadowWidth == 0)
    {
        [self.layer setMasksToBounds:NO ];
        [self.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor ] CGColor ] ];
        [self.layer setShadowOpacity:0.5 ];
        [self.layer setShadowRadius:5.0 ];
        [self.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake( 0 , 0 ) ];
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    }
    [self.layer setShadowPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:bounds ] CGPath ] ];

    if ([ChosenCategory getInstance].doesExist) {
        if ([ChosenCategory getInstance].category == self.ingredientCategory) {
            [self.btnAddOrRemove setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Edit profile", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.btnAddOrRemove setButtonColor:[UIColor ht_mediumColor]];
            [self.btnAddOrRemove setShadowColor:[UIColor ht_mediumDarkColor]];
            [self.btnAddOrRemove setTitleColor:[UIColor ht_ashColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.btnAddOrRemove setTitleColor:[UIColor ht_ashColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            [self.btnAddOrRemove addTarget:self action:@selector(toDetail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
        else {
            [self.btnAddOrRemove setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Choose Profile", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.btnAddOrRemove setButtonColor:[UIColor ht_bitterSweetColor]];
            [self.btnAddOrRemove setShadowColor:[UIColor ht_bitterSweetDarkColor]];
            [self.btnAddOrRemove setTitleColor:[UIColor ht_ashColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.btnAddOrRemove setTitleColor:[UIColor ht_ashColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            [self.btnAddOrRemove addTarget:self action:@selector(chosenProfile:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
    }
    else {
        [self.btnAddOrRemove setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Choose profile", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnAddOrRemove setButtonColor:[UIColor ht_mediumColor]];
        [self.btnAddOrRemove setShadowColor:[UIColor ht_mediumDarkColor]];
        [self.btnAddOrRemove setTitleColor:[UIColor ht_ashColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnAddOrRemove setTitleColor:[UIColor ht_ashColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [self.btnAddOrRemove addTarget:self action:@selector(chosenProfile:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    [self.btnContainerView addSubview:self.btnAddOrRemove];

    self.shadowWidth = bounds.size.width;
    self.lblSummary.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.lblSummary.frame.size.width;
}
}
```

[image]

But as you can see the custom button doesn't get the full width of the containerView. It also doesn't center correctly.

So I've got 2 questions:

1) How can I add the custom button to the view where it uses the full width of the container UIView, while using AutoLayout.

2) Is there a way I could add whitespace to the left and right of the cards?

Comment: You say in your first question, "while using auto layout", but you're not using auto layout between your button and its container. Instead of setting the button's frame, pin it to all four sides of the container view with constraints.

Comment: @rdelmar thanks for your answer. how could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using constraints on all other views, I would suggest you do the same for the button. Instead of using the static frame, you could try using some visual layout constraints for setting the frame on your button

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{

    self.btnAddOrRemove = [[HTPressableButton alloc] initWithFrame:self.btnContainerView.bounds buttonStyle:HTPressableButtonStyleRounded];
    [self.btnContainerView addSubView:self.btnAddOrRemove];
    [self.btnAddOrRemove setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.btnAddOrRemove addConstraintsToFillParentHorizontally:self.btnContainerView]
    [self.btnAddOrRemove addConstraintsToFillParentVertically:self.btnContainerView]
}

- (void)addConstraintsToFillParentHorizontally:(UIView *)parentView
{
    [parentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{ @"view": self }]];
}

- (void)addConstraintsToFillParentVertically:(UIView *)parentView
{
    [parentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{ @"view": self }]];
}
```

This should make the frame of the button match the one of the container view. Then all you still need to do is apply the rounded corners in the layoutSubviews method

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    if (self.shadowWidth == 0)
    {
        [self.layer setMasksToBounds:NO ];
        [self.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
        [self.layer setShadowOpacity:0.5 ];
        [self.layer setShadowRadius:5.0 ];
        [self.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 0)];
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    }
    [self.layer setShadowPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:bounds ] CGPath ] ];
}
```

Hope it works!

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I've chosen to implement a different library that enables me to declare the custom button in Interface Builder, so that problem isn't the case anymore. My second question still remains though (how to decrease the width of the custom 'cards')

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can leave the button as it is if you want just set your place holder view background color to transparent

```
UIColor.clearcolor()
```

and to center your bottom put `UIButton` rect same size place holder view and then set content mode of your button to enter background image inside!!!

```
contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
```